# Remove parent entity without removing children (jpa)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to remove list of parent without removing children

The parent :

```
@Entity
public class Parent {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "PARENTID")
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, mappedBy = "parent")
    private Set<Child> childs = new HashSet<Child>();

 ...
}
```

The child:

```
@Entity
public class Child {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "CHILDID")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="PARENTID", nullable = false)
    private Parent parent;

  ...
}
```

What i did is to update all children using HQL query, and then delete the list of parents using HQL query as well.

The problem is that this way is too heavy, is there any simple solution using JPA ?

Comment: You can use JPA Bulk update to null out all children referencing a parent in your list, and a bulk delete to then remove all parents in the list.  Is this what you did in HQL?

Comment: Could you post your code that updates first and then deletes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mapping as it is does not allow for a simple deletion of parents with their children. It does not support having a `Child` without a `Parent` (`nullable = false`).

You either need to

- set the parent id to a 'surrogate' `Parent` before removal of the parents. You can do it by a bulk update or by fetching the parents that are about to be deleted, iterate over the children and reset the parent references. Whether you use bulk updates or object manipulation depends on how you would remove the parents. If you remove the parents with a bulk query, use a bulk query for the children as well. In general I would use the object approach as the safer one. The bulk query is more compact.
- drop the nullability constraint and change the provided cascade. Remove the `REMOVE` cascade from the `@OneToMany` mapping and you can remove parents as you like.

Answer (score 4):

you could set your Cascade in the following section to not delete

```
 @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, mappedBy = "parent")
private Set<Child> childs = new HashSet<Child>();
```

by editing the annotation as follows:

```
 @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST}, mappedBy = "parent")
```

and whatever other CascadeType options you need ( see [CascadeType Enums](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/CascadeType.html)). This will make it so that when you delete the parents, the children won't be deleted as well.